# InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, external-content-type

How to enable this feature? "InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list." I want to edit the form in infopath and publish it back to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Install the following software:
1. Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0
2. Microsoft .NET Framework 4
3. WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you are trying to customize document library form in Infopath which is not supported by Infopath

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2009/12/17/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-using-infopath-2010.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments